React complains about different number of hooks used while switching between routes
I'm trying to implement MVVM pattern in my React application. Let's assume for simplicity that the project structure looks as follows:
src/
- mvvm-stuff/
  - ...
- Component1/
  - Component1View.tsx
  - useComponent1ViewModel.ts
- Component2/
  - Component2View.tsx
  - useComponent2ViewModel.ts
- AppView.tsx
- useAppView.ts
- index.tsx

In the index.tsx there's a router with links and it navigates to component1 and component2 routes to view their corresponding views with their view models.
The useComponent1ViewModel.ts uses useState hook twice.
The useComponent2ViewMode.ts uses useState hook once.
The problem is when a user navigates between these two routes, it gets the error
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

If I add an additional call to useState in the useComponent2ViewMode.ts to create a second state var, the error disappears.
I struggle to resolve that. According to the rules of hooks in the React, each component works independently and can has different number of hooks used. The important thing is to preserve the order and number of hooks in each component - which is preserved in this case. So why such error comes out?

Please [edit] to share a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so readers can see what your code is doing. If I had to hazard a guess you are conditionally calling these hooks somehow.
